# Python script with flask - how to enable setup on windows server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, python-windows-bundle

I have a python script with flask API. I am running the code in command line `python scriptname.py` and making an POST call and it works.

But in realtime how to enable this set up on windows server, so that script is running and available anytime for third-party to make HTTP post. Any pointers please.

```
class Impersonate:
    def __init__(self,login,password):
        self.domain='<domain>'
        self.login=login
        self.password=password

    def logon(self):
        self.handel=win32security.LogonUser(self.login,self.domain,self.password,win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
        win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(self.handel)
    def logoff(self):
        win32security.RevertToSelf() #terminates impersonation
        self.handel.Close() #guarantees cleanup



a=Impersonate('testuser','password]')

try:
    a.logon() #become the user
    print(a.login)
    a.logoff() #return to normal
except:
    pass
    
    
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Hellow(Resource):
    def post(self):
        path = os.path.join(parentdir, dirname)
        try:
           os.makedirs(path)
           resp = Response('{} successfully created.)
        
        
api.add_resource(Hellow, '/test')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(port=5000, host="<hostname>" use_reloader=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to deploy the flask backend on server or on windows you can use "start /b python xyz.py". Or can also have a look at https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: I used AlwaysUp to convert the python script as windows service.Which works. But is there is any way to leverage Windows IIS